# TouchableHighlight on DrawerLayoutAndroid

Tags: android, react-native, drawerlayout

I'm using `DrawerLayourAndroid`. I want to navigate to another View by `TouchableHighlight` in `DrawerLayout`. Here's my code for `DrawableLayout`:

```
var drawerLayout = (
  <View>
    <TouchableHighlight onPress=
      {()=>this.props.navigator.push({name:'secView', component:secView})}>
      <Text>move</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  </View>
);
```

But it has the error "`undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigator')`".
How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used react-native's Navigator when I posted this post. And I solved this problem by using react-native-router-flux at here.
https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux

I used Actions.name(params) in my custom drawer, and it works!